# Как использовать 2 Git на проекте?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-commit, git-push

Хочу использовать на проекте 2 Git'a. Сейчас проект находится на Heroku. Пользуюсь их системой контроля. Но появилась необходимость в использовании Github или Gitlab - неважно. На Github/Gitlab я хочу лить **только одну папку из проекта**. Первый Git отлично работает. Делаю так:

```
git add .
git commit -am "text"
git push heroku master
```

Подскажите, плз, алгоритм добавления второго git на github/gitlab, и, как туда заливать только одну папку?

Comment: Сделать эту папку сабмодулем.

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее. Я совсем новичок в этом деле. Хотя бы просто алгоритм на словах, например, создаёте новый гит, делаете вот так, вот и так.

Comment: есть документация https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8#r_git_submodules  вот только если просто папку сделать сабмодулем по этому же пути, можно получить кучу веселья. Скорее всего Вам это не нужно. Распишите чуть детальней, что именно хранится должно в этой отдельной папке и может быть есть решение попроще/получше.

Comment: Смотрите, сейчас у меня на проекте нет админки - я всё делаю в редакторе. Прикручивать админку - пока вообще не хочу. Потому что я сам могу всё сделать в коде + не так много информации, чтобы её через админку постить. Но, я иногда даю почитать информацию товарищу. Он находит какие-то опечатки, ошибочки (сугубо по контенту, не по коду). Потом скидывает мне в телеграме скринами где ошибки и что исправить. Я хочу папку с контентом положить на github/gitlab, чтобы он мог зайти, там исправить ошибки, а я, если согласен с ними, просто скачал файлы и запушил на сервер. Своеобразная админка такая=)

Comment: ага, то есть, это два достаточно разных куска.  Можно сделать самбодулем, а можно просто сделать два рядом стоящих репозитория (один с кодом, другой с данными) и работать с ними независимо. Если же хочется именно сабмодуль, то рекомендую сделать для данных отдельную новую папку, скопировать туда данные. Создать сабмодуль в новой папке с данными. добавить этот сабмодуль в основной проект. По старому месту данные удалить и закоммитить все.вместе. Правда я не знаю, захочет ли так heroku

Comment: А я смогу сабмодуль лить в другую систему контроля (github, gitlab)?

Comment: gitlab/github - это не другая система контроля версий. Если там используется git, то конечно можно. даже на битбакет.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать. Надеюсь через пару часов отвечу на свой же вопрос с инструкцией=)

Comment: оно не сложно, но теперь главный репозиторий будет содержать привязку к какому то коммиту в сабмодуле. Вначале это кажется супернелогичным, но потом все стает на свои места

Comment: Не совсем понял. Что это означает? Какой процесс вообще будет? Я представляю себе так: 
1. git add (папка с контентом)
2. git commit
3. git push на Github
4. git clone с гитхаба
5. git push на Heroku
Верно?

Comment: У Вас будет как минимум два разных случая. Папку с контентом Вы будете обновлять независимо. А в основном репозитории нужно будет добавлять самбодуль как "измененный файл" и коммитить/пушить

Comment: Понял, спасибо!